# Show that $| e^{-2\pi ixh} - 1|< \epsilon$ when $h$ is small

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following integral

$$\int_{-N}^N | e^{-2\pi ixh} -1| dx$$

where $N>0$ is some fixed real number, and $i$ is imaginary unit. I would like to conclude that given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $h_0>0$ such that when $|h| < h_0$,

$$| e^{-2\pi ixh} -1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \forall x\in[-N,N]$$

But I couldn't figure out how? It looks quite obvious but I forgot which theorem/property supports it. I guess I got confused because it's a complex function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a function $f(x,h)=e^{-2\pi ixh}$ defined on $[-N,N]\times [-1,1]$. Since the domain is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous. So for a given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $||(x,h)-(y,k)||<\delta$ implies $|f(x,h)-f(y,k)|<\epsilon /2$. Now find a sufficient $\delta'$ so that $|h|<\delta'$ implies $|f(x,0)-f(x,h)|<\epsilon /2$.

Comment: Somehow totally forgot "uniformly continuous"... Thanks.